# NgOnInit called twice

Tags: angular, angular-component-life-cycle

I have a page that is behind a guard, and on the ngOnInit I usually do a subscription to a context management server that consists of first a post to create a subscription then opening a websocket connection with the server. On my local copy everything seems to work fine... But recently i've noticed in the production build it sometimes does the subscription twice which leads me to believe that ngOnInit is being called twice. I'am not sure why this is happening.

At the moment my solution was to just move this subscription code to a service and have it called once from app components ngOnInit.

Comment: you should post your actual code and what leads you to believe this

Comment: As general idea: a ngOnInit happens when you make visible the component -because of an *ngIf, or because of the component appear in the aplication-

Comment: @Eliseo Your are totally right, though right now this is happening on the dashboard page which is behind a guard and is only redirected to, once the token is valid. So in theory it should not be being loaded in twice.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using a Auth lib and i had the post_login url and the redirect url poiniting to a redirection page, turns out one was supposed to be a redirect and the other is used as a page to load once log in is complete, so after pointing post_login_url to "/" it seemed to fix the issue. Though the one question in my mind is, even though 2 redirects were happening, why would that trigger ngOnInit twice and like the same component was loaded twice on one page? Shouldn't it be as if the page had just reloaded instead?